# Не могу разобраться с API сайта

Tags: api

Не могу разобраться как составить API запрос к этому сайту. Мне бы пример какой-нибудь, по нему все пойму. Хелпаните)

https://smosmm.com/api

Comment: Выполнить POST запрос по адресу https://smosmm.com/api/v2 с параметрами например: key=xxxxxxx action=services. В ответ придёт json. key надо получить с сайта

Comment: Можете привести пример полного запроса?

Comment: На каком языке программирования?

Comment: Можно на питоне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример:

```
import requests

url = 'https://smosmm.com/api/v2'
myobj = {'key': 'yourKey', 'action':'services'}

x = requests.post(url, data=myobj, timeout=3.0)

print(x.text)
```

Ответ

{"error":"API key hatal\u0131","status":"102"}

Я key - то не знаю :)

Ошибки обрабатывать так:

```
try:
    x = requests.post(url, data=myobj, timeout=3.0)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    # Maybe set up for a retry, or continue in a retry loop
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    # Tell the user their URL was bad and try a different one
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    # catastrophic error. bail.
    raise SystemExit(e)
```

Comment: Если подходит - закрывайте вопрос и ставте галочку:)

Comment: Погодите, а если запрос будет длиться больше 3 секунд? Тогда у вас код сломается?

Comment: Тогда ошибка будет